# Changing color/style of SVG fill with CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this SVG script inside some html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Circle {
        fill: #ff6666;
     }

     #bin {
        fill: #fff;
     }

     .Line {
        fill: #cccccc;
     }
</style>                                               
<g>
    <circle class="Circle" id="OuterCircle" cx="15.8" cy="15.2" r="15.2" />

    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M9.6,7.6C9.2,7.8,9,8.3,9.1,8.6c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5h12.5c0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.5-1c-0.1-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.5h-9H9.6z" />
    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M13.9,6.7c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.7-1,1c0.3,0,0.6,0,1,0c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5h3.8c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0.3,0,0.7,0,1,0c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.7-1-1C16.6,6,15.1,5.9,13.9,6.7z" />
    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M9.6,9.6h12.5l-1,14.9c0,0-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0-0.5,0c-2.9,0-5.8,0-8.7,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.4-0.5-0.5C10.2,19.5,9.9,14.5,9.6,9.6z" />       

    <polygon class="Line" points="14.5,12 17.1,12 16.7,22.8 15,22.8 " />
    <path class="Line" d="M18,12v10.8h1.7c0.3-3.8,0.6-7.5,0.9-11.3C19.8,11.7,18.9,11.8,18,12z" />
    <path class="Line" d="M11,11.5c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.3,2.6,0.5v10.8h-1.7C11.9,22.8,11.9,22.8,11,11.5z" />   
</g>
```

I am trying to style it so that when you hover over the class "Path", it changes the style of the class "OuterCircle". The CSS I've tried so far doesn't seem to working.

The current CSS for hover I have so far is:

```
.Circle:hover {
    fill: #97D0FF;
}

g.Path:hover > #OuterCircle {
    fill: #97D0FF;
}
```

I've tried using different sibling combinators but nothing seems to work, and placing the circle attribute underneath the path attribute messes up the svg image. I'm not really sure how this works with svg.

Comment: I can't simulate your issue, but I see you have a extra `.Path` in your `g.Path:hover > #OuterCircle` CSS. Remove it if your `g` doesn't have this class.

Comment: Same here, applying `.Circle:hover {fill: #97D0FF;}` seems to work for me.

Comment: The second CSS block that I've stated doesn't actually do anything. I just included it as one of my attempts of trying to achieve what I want. - Sorry if that was confusing.

The `.Circle:hover {fill: #97D0FF; }` does work fine, but there's a path on my svg image that I want to add a hover to, that will also style the circle. So far, hovering it over the path doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a "previous sibling" selector in CSS, so you can't style `#OuterCircle` on `.Path:hover`.

But, you can add a class to the parent group and style `#OuterCircle` when the group is hovered.

```css
.Circle {
  fill: #ff6666;
}

#bin {
  fill: #fff;
}

.Line {
  fill: #cccccc;
}

g.icon:hover #OuterCircle {
  fill: #97D0FF;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="icon">
    <circle class="Circle" id="OuterCircle" cx="15.8" cy="15.2" r="15.2" />

    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M9.6,7.6C9.2,7.8,9,8.3,9.1,8.6c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.5,0.5h12.5c0.4-0.2,0.6-0.6,0.5-1c-0.1-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.5h-9H9.6z" />
    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M13.9,6.7c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.7-1,1c0.3,0,0.6,0,1,0c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5h3.8c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0.3,0,0.7,0,1,0c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.7-1-1C16.6,6,15.1,5.9,13.9,6.7z" />
    <path class="Path" id="bin" d="M9.6,9.6h12.5l-1,14.9c0,0-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0-0.5,0c-2.9,0-5.8,0-8.7,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.4-0.5-0.5C10.2,19.5,9.9,14.5,9.6,9.6z" />       

    <polygon class="Line" points="14.5,12 17.1,12 16.7,22.8 15,22.8 " />
    <path class="Line" d="M18,12v10.8h1.7c0.3-3.8,0.6-7.5,0.9-11.3C19.8,11.7,18.9,11.8,18,12z" />
    <path class="Line" d="M11,11.5c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.3,2.6,0.5v10.8h-1.7C11.9,22.8,11.9,22.8,11,11.5z" />   
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: OF COURSE! This is what I needed, thanks very much @pan.goth